# Text search in Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

How do I find a stored procedure containing a certain text? While I understand that the best place to do this kind of searching is through your source control tool, but are there ways to do this in the database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%your text here%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: Be aware routine_definition is cropped at 4000 chars just in case you have a long procedure. sys.sql_modules doesn't have the same issue.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects  o 
    ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%Serach_Text%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx). Definition contains the text of procedures. The view contains procedures, views, udfs etc. To restrict yourself to stored procedures you should join with [sys.procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx) on object_id.